# Google Maps only loading over wifi but doesn't load on 3G

Tags: android, google-maps

So the title pretty much says it all. I am trying to load a Google Map V2 which only loads when Wi-Fi is present on my device and doesn't load when I'm on 3G. However when I run it first on Wi-Fi then run it for a second time on 3G WIHOUT clearing the data or uninstalling the application it works. So my question is how can I make my new installed application loads the map over 3G from the FIRST time?

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with your phone or its settings than the programming behind it.

Comment: Do you have any idea what can it be?

Answer (score 7):

Okay I solved the problem. Turned out I chose to restrict background data of Google Play services. Once I unchecked it, it worked correctly.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot, lot of swearing. It looks like google apps are not able to identify problems with disabled background data, and are not able to inform the user in a reasonable way that they need that feature enabled.

Comment: This may also be called "Google Services Framework" or something else equally obscure. In my case i had it blocked from using mobile data, although background data was enabled for all apps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your device allows location services only when wifi is connected

Comment: It is enabled. Also Google Maps operate normally when I'm on 3G. The map just doesn't load inside the application I built.